# How to add the content of script using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use aws_sagemaker_studio_lifecycle_config using the [aws_sagemaker_studio_lifecycle_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_studio_lifecycle_config)
as per the document

```
studio_lifecycle_config_content - (Required) The ****content**** of your Studio Lifecycle Configuration script. This content must be base64 encoded.
```

now my question is how to add the content of the script from a location?
The script is in bash.

Comment: Use [filebase64](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/filebase64).

Answer (score 0):

So instead base64encode use filebase64 ....